# Correlate server metrics from visual studio load test

Tags: visual-studio, azure, testing, azure-devops

I have a coded web test being executed in visual studio load test. I deploy it so it runs in Azure. The analysis is pretty cool, but I can't seem to figure out how to correlate remote server metrics into my load test results (i.e. metrics of the server receiving my load test requests).

From what I can tell, it seems like I might have to install the "agent" software on my remote server. How would I do this with an Azure cloud service deployment? It doesn't seem possible with a cloud service deployment.

Also, it looks like a load test can aggregate App Insight data, but from what I can tell, App Insight doesn't give me the low-lever metrics I'm looking for. I was "perf"-like data: Counters for CPU/Disk/Network/Kernel/etc. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Does anyone know of a way to automatically include remote server metrics into a Visual Studio load test?

Answer (score 1):

A load test can collect performance counters from other computers. It should be able to collect any counter that Perfmon running on the computer running the load test can see. If you set the permissions and firewalls etc so the computer that runs the tests can run Perfmon and collect the counters then the load test should also be able to collect them.

A load test that is run in the cloud using VSTS is run under a Microsoft account from one of their computers. This means setting the permissions etc on the servers being load tested is difficult because the accounts are unknown.

If a load test is run on your own computers then you know the accounts running the tests and can set the server permissions to allow those accounts the appropriate accesses.

Visual Studio agents can be used on your computers to run the load tests. They are most commonly used when the load required (the number of virtual users) is too high for one computer. Agents do not run on the servers being tested. The Agent software is not used when a cloud load test is run by VSTS. (Actually it might be used by Microsoft, but it will be almost invisible to you when you run a test with VSTS.)